# How to store Image in mongodb as sequential name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to store image in mongodb how it has store that thing i know very well. but i have to create image name as sequential i don't have any idea how to do that.

```
/image01.jpg
/image02.jpg
/image03.jpg
/image04.jpg ............ infinite
```

That's way i have to save image name in Node. Please any on give me any idea how to do that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think creating index for image name would do the trick:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

db.collection.ensureIndex({"imageName":1})

where your docs would be:

```
{"imageName":"/image001.jpg"},
{"imageName":"/image002.jpg"},
etc
```

edit:

then when quering the data use orderBy or sort imageName to get it in sorted order.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

Comment: It's automatic created name? We have to put some string like '/image'+i+'.jpg' ; something like that.. Where i increment by 1.

Comment: @GunjanPatel So why did you accept the answer if it does not answer your question? Indexes do not create values, they are just indexes. And as shown here, not even a unique index to enforce that the names are not duplicated.